# Summing up all previous numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to implement an algorithm which takes the first element and build the sum like that:

[image]

In fact, I am taking the 1 element and build the sum, then the 1st and the 2nd and build the sum, then the 1st, 2nd and 3rd and build the sum etc.

I tried:

```
                    for (int l = 0; l < valueList.size(); l++) {
                        double result = ((valueList.get(0) + valueList.get(l)) * (l + 1))/2;
                        resultList.add(result);
                    }
```

However this does not seem to work. How to implement such an algorithm?

I would appreciate your answers!

Comment: int toAdd = 1;
    int curr = 0;
    for(int l = 0; l < valueList.size(); l++)
    {
      curr += toAdd;
      toAdd++;
      resultList.add(curr);
    }

Comment: @AdamFolwarczny Thx for your answer. However I do not get what you really mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
for (int l = 0; l < valueList.size(); l++) {

    double result = ((l>0) ? resultList.get(l-1) : 0) + valueList.get(l);
    resultList.add(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That algorithm is similar to the factorial function:

```
f(x) = x + f(x-1)
```

You could implement that recursively:

```
public int sum(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return 0;

    }
    return x + sum(x - 1);
}
```

or iteratively:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = x; i > 0; i--) {
    sum += i;

}
```